# Capsule diagram based Java multy-thread program

Tags: java, multithreading, uml, signals, state-machine

I have a java program based ona capsule diagram, where i have 3 classes capsule, port and  state_machine. A stat machina at a state prnts the nr of its state. The working principle of the program is like [this](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/193Xxmg44ogTGnS6HKrk8Xxg0xclertKnWvCAHGoxq-M/edit)

The mian:

```
public class SimpleCapsule {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    Port p2=new Port(null);

    Capsule1 c1= new Capsule1(3,1, p2, null);
    Capsule1 c2= new Capsule1(2,-3, null, p2);    

    //while ( false ){
        c1.state.start();
        c2.state.start();
      //  }
   }
}
```

Port:

> public class Port {
>
> ```
> private Port connect;
> public boolean signal=true;
>
> public Port (Port c){
>     this.connect=c;
>     }
>  public void snedSignal(boolean b){
>     if (this.connect!=null){
>     this.connect.signal=b;
>     } 
> }
> ```
>
> public boolean getSignal(){
>       return this.signal;
>       }
>            }

Capsule:

```
 public class Capsule1 {
      public StateMachine1 state; public Port port;    

 public Capsule1 (int i, int signal, Port connecte, Port thisPort){

     if (thisPort!=null){
         this.port=thisPort;
         }else{
         port=new Port(connecte);
         }    

     state= new StateMachine1 (i,signal,this.port);
     }

 }
```

State machine:

```
public class StateMachine1 extends Thread{
    public boolean signal=false;
    public int nr, signalSend;    
    public Port port;

    public StateMachine1(int i, int signalNr, Port p){
        this.nr=i;        
        this.signalSend=signalNr;
        this.port=p;
    }    


    @Override
    public void run(){        
        System.out.println(nr+"started");
    while (true){
        if (this.port.getSignal()){
            for (int i=0; i<this.nr;i++){                
                System.out.println(nr+"th: "+i+" sS");                                            
                    if (signalSend==i){
                        port.snedSignal(true);                            
                    }else{
                        port.snedSignal(false);                        
                    }   
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(StateMachine1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

        }else{
            System.out.print(nr+"TH-"+this.port.getSignal()+" ");                    
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Like this the program works well, but if u comment the last raw from the state machine class:  `System.out.print(nr+"TH-"+this.port.getSignal()+" ");` than the second state machine **SM2** does not receives after the 3rd or 4th signals to start.

What is the problem? Where did i made a mistake in this signaling process?

Comment: How did you detect, that `SM2` does not receive signals after commenting mentioned line?

Comment: only the SM1 was printing the numbers, however the Boolean was sent true. However it receives the signal when i have that print raw.

Comment: Why -1? Badly formulated question?